# Copying parameter pack from one template to another and using result simultaneously in inner alias

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, traits

I've shrunk my problem down to this code which fails to compile:

```
#include <tuple>

template <class... Left>
struct Split {
        template <class... Right>
        using type = std::tuple<std::pair<Left,Right>...>;
};

template <template<class...>class Result>
struct Deduce {
        template <template<class...>class Source, class... Parameters>
        constexpr static Result<Parameters...> type_from_ret(Source<Parameters...>);

        template <typename Source>
        using type = decltype(type_from_ret(std::declval<Source>()));
};

int main() {
        Deduce<Split<>::type>::template type<std::tuple<>> a;
        return 0;
}
```

Giving:

```
 In substitution of 'template<class ... Left> template<class ... Right> using type = std::tuple<std::pair<Left, Right>...> [with Right = {Parameters ...}; Left = {}]':
19:41:   required from 'struct Deduce<Split<>::type>'
26:23:   required from here
13:51: error: mismatched argument pack lengths while expanding 'std::pair<Left, Right>'
  using type = std::tuple<std::pair<Left,Right>...>;
```

Is this my error or a compiler error?  Is there a way to form these simultaneous pairs (one from an exact type, one from an outer class) that will succeed?

I've been using this `struct Deduce` approach to copy parameter packs from a templated class type to another template in a generic way.  It's been working fine up until this use with simultaneous packs.  I'm not attached to this particular solution.

The problem I'm trying to solve involves enforcing compile-time requirements on parameter packs passed to a base class.  I have a couple `struct Split`-like requirements templates which derived classes select the template parameters for and pass as a type parameter to the templated based class, along with a tuple type of the value types they are using.  I was hoping the base class could then exercise SFINAE to only allow that derived class to be used if its argument types passed the checks enforced by the requirements type.  This is so that I don't have to add a bunch of enable_if's to every single derived class, as there are only a few classes of these checks.

I'm sending a std::tuple type up to the base class rather than a straight parameter pack because a parameter pack terminates the template parameter list, and then I don't have anywhere to put the enable_if to check the requirements.  So I'm attempting to copy the parameter pack out of the tuple, but this is not working because of this issue.  A way to make use of SFINAE on a class that takes a parameter pack (where the SFINAE relies on the contents of the pack) would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by replacing Deduce's pattern of determining the return value of an overloaded function with the simpler `mp_rename` template specialization seen at http://pdimov.com/cpp2/simple_cxx11_metaprogramming.html

```
template <template<class...>class Result, class Source> struct Deduce;

template <template<class...>class Result, template<class...>class Source, class... Parameters>
struct Deduce<Result,Source<Parameters...>> {
        using type=Result<Parameters...>;
};

int main() {
        Deduce<Split<>::type,std::tuple<>> a;
        return 0;
}
```